# How do I get my file properties to display in the properties window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, py2exe

I want to be able to right click on my .exe I made with python and go to properties and view the file version, Product name, File description, ect. How can I get these properties to display using python?

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to fix the issue and add the properties details by adding some things to my setup file. This is what it looks like:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    sys.argv.append("py2exe")
    sys.argv.append("-q")

class Target:
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        self.__dict__.update(kw)
        self.version = "2.0.0.1"
        self.company_name = "CompanyName"
        self.copyright = "Copyright (c) 2015 CompanyName"
        self.name = "FileName"

target = Target(
    description = "FileDescription",
    script = "Script.py",
    dest_base = "ProgramName")

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 2,
                          'compressed': True}},
    zipfile = None,
    windows = [target]
)
```